# How to get primitive type Lists/Arrays to show that way in Swagger.io for ServiceStack

Tags: servicestack, swagger

For some reason my Array/List properties of Request DTOs don't show up as such, but as Data Type 'string'

When I use ApiMembers like this:

```
    [ApiMember]
    public int[] BlogIds { get; set; }
```

The will show up as 'string' in the Swagger.io for ServiceStack list of parameters with the following attributes:

```
Parameter Type: Query
Data Type: string
```

[image: Swagger UI]

It does work for the Response schema, where is shows the JSON as:

```
"BlogIds": [
"int"
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs to be sent as a string on the QueryString.

ServiceStack allows you to send [complex objects on the QueryString using the JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string) which Swagger doesn't understand.

But it does let you send a comma-delimited string:

```
BlogIds 1,2,3
```

You can also choose be more explicit by including the `[]` brackets, e.g:

```
BlogIds [1,2,3]
```

Comment: Just found that out myself, but you were quicker! Would it be possible to the YAML / a Swagger Editor compatible format to make that visible to the consumers of the service?

Comment: @Gabriël Can't support multiple queryString parsing formats so it would need to be configurable, but [no-one has requested it yet](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests) so wouldn't be a great feature to support competing strategies if the non-default will never get used, just adds unnecessary complexity in code-base + docs. TBH We're more likely to add an alternative to Swagger UI, something more optimized which we have complete control of.